# Javascript/Jquery - how to append the state/city fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, textfield

EDIT

I am still baby in writing Javascript and I need your help in understanding how it works so please bear with me.

Say, if I want to have "Singapore" append to the textfield on the webpage automatically when the user picks "Singapore" in country select dropdown, how or where do I need to append the "Singapore" text to the state/city textfields on webpage? See image example.

[image]

**HTML code**

[image]

**Javascript**

```
function appendtoText(){

var country = document.getElementById("billing_country_select");
var state = document.getElementById("billing_province_input");
var city = document.getElementById("billing_city");
if (country.value == "Singapore"){

    state.value = state.append("Singapore");
    alert(state.value);
    city.append("Singapore");

}
```

}

I am not sure where I went wrong with this. State and City don't show the appended text: Singapore. So please correct me if I went wrong in coding.

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the value of the Country field to the state field:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('$billing_country').change(function() {
        $('$billing_province_input').val(' - ' + $('$billing_country').val());
    });
});
```

When the Billing Country field is changed, the Billing State/Province value automatically becomes " - *Billing Country*".  If the chosen country were Singapore, it would become " - Singapore".  I'm making a very simple assumption about how you want this to work, so if this isn't what you need, let me know and I will refine it as needed.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, I am guessing that it is not going to work well especially with different variables?

Comment: @Josephine:  I'll double check the code, I didn't have time to test it last night.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - okay. I will be waiting. and thank you in advance.

Comment: I added some more code to make it complete.  Try this in a script tag and let me know if it works.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams -- almost there. I need to set if conditional. Eg if the country is equal to Singapore, then state/city should be set to Singapore.

Comment: @Surreal Dreams - alright! I got it wrong. Thank you so much for your help!